# Unable to get scsi device path (st) device path for IBM LTO7 drives

Tags: scsi

when we execute the `lsscsi -g |grep -i ult` command we get list of all LTO7 drives of IBM company.

here we are able to see the st path for the drives.

no scsi id's generated for lto7 drives.

its showing blank .. how to get it back ?

```
[4:0:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st0   /dev/sg275
[4:0:1:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st1   /dev/sg276
[4:0:2:0]    tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      FA14  -         /dev/sg277
[4:0:3:0]    tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      M570  -         /dev/sg278
[6:0:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st4   /dev/sg550
[6:0:1:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st5   /dev/sg551
[6:0:2:0]    tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      FA14  -         /dev/sg552
[6:0:3:0]    tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      M570  -         /dev/sg553
[8:0:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st2   /dev/sg1103
[8:0:1:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st3   /dev/sg1104
[8:0:2:0]    tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      FA14  -         /dev/sg1105
[8:0:3:0]    tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      M570  -         /dev/sg1106
[10:0:0:0]   tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st8   /dev/sg1032
[10:0:1:0]   tape    HP       Ultrium 5-SCSI   I6PS  /dev/st9   /dev/sg1035
[10:0:2:0]   tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      FA14  -         /dev/sg1039
[10:0:3:0]   tape    IBM      ULTRIUM-TD7      M570  -         /dev/sg1101
```